# Estimating the Length of a Coin Tossing Game

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales

I am looking to solve the following:

A person plays a coin tossing game where he receives $1$ point for every heads and $5$ points for every tails.  The game stops when he receives $1,000$ points.  Estimate within $\pm{2}$ the expectation of the length of the coin tossing game.

I know this is discrete martingale problem but I'm not sure how to approach it.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with martingales, but couldn't you estimate it by saying that   the expected amount of points gained per flip is $E(x) = (0.5)(1) + (0.5)(5) = 3$ then doing $1000/3 =333.33... \approx 334$ flips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expected number of points per game is $3$. You can then check that $M_n = \sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-3) = (\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)-3n = S_n-3n$ is a martingale, where $X_i$ is the number of points scored on round $i$ of the game, and $S_n$ is the total number of points scored by time $n$. Let $\tau$ be the first time $S_n \geq 1000$, i.e. the time the game stops. On one hand, $M$ is a martingale and $\tau$ is a bounded stopping time $(\tau \leq 1000)$, so optional stopping theorem tells us $E[M_\tau] = M_0 = 0$.
On the other hand, $E[M_\tau] = E[S_\tau] - 3E[\tau]$.
By definition, $1000\leq S_\tau \leq 1004 = 999+5$.
Rearranging, we have $E[\tau] = E[S_\tau]/3$, so
$$
\frac{1000}{3} \leq E[\tau] \leq \frac{1004}{3}.
$$

Comment: +1 but there is a minor problem in your definition of $M_n$. The index $i$ should start at $1$, not $0$.

Comment: How do we know $1000 \le S_{\tau} \le 1004$ by definition?

Comment: $\tau$ is the **first** time you have more than $1000$ points. By definition you must have at least $1000$ points at time $\tau$. You cannot have more than $1004$ because if you did, then at time $\tau-1$ you would still have at least $1000$ points because the most you can gain in one step is $5$ points.